# 99 bottles of beer on the wall code

Tags: java

The assignment was to, "design and implement an application that prints the first few verses of the traveling song “One Hundred Bottles of Beer.” Use a loop such that each iteration prints one verse. Read the number of verses to print from the use and validate the input."  I'm having some trouble coming up with a for loop. This is what I have so far but I'm pretty sure I'm way off. Any pointers?

```
    int verse;
    int count;
    System.out.println("number of verses?");
    verse = scan.nextInt();
    for(count= verse; count >= (verse - 3); count--)
    {
        System.out.println(verse + " bottles of beer on the wall");
        System.out.println(verse + " bottles of beer");
        System.out.println("If one of those bottles should happen to fall");
        System.out.println(count + " bottles of beer on the wall");
        System.out.println(count + " bottles of beer on the wall");
        System.out.println(count + " bottles of beer");
        System.out.println("If one of those bottles should happen to fall");
        System.out.println(count + " bottles of beer on the wall");

    }
```

Comment: What trouble are you having, exactly?

Comment: https://almnet.de/esolang/hq9plus.php

Comment: I'm having trouble getting it to stop after the first verse. Ideally if I entered 100 it would run the song in its entirety and if I entered 5 it would run from there. Also, when I try to run the program it prints the desired verse and then returns to the initial verse entered and ends the last sentence of the second verse with the correct number. I.e. 100 bottles of beer --> 99 bottles; 100 bottles of beer --> 98 bottles etc...

Answer (score 0):

You should declare your count in the `for` expression, not outside the for loop. You also only need 3 lines of the song because they get repeated until the loop is done.

```
for (int count = verse; count >= 3; count--) {
    System.out.println(count + " bottles of beer on the wall");
    System.out.println(count + " bottles of beer");
    System.out.println("If one of those bottles should happen to fall");
    System.out.println((count - 1) + " bottles of beer on the wall");
}
```

Your biggest issue was that you had `verse` all the way through your loop but it didn't change. `count` is what tracked the current index of the loop, while `verse` just kept track of how many loops to perform.

Note the last line has `(count - 1)` to temporarily display the next number it will decrement to.

Additionally, I removed the `(verse - 3)` and replaced it with `3` because I assumed you wanted to loop until only 3 bottles were left. Change this number to `1` otherwise.

Comment: The last line would actually be "`n - 1` bottles of beer on the wall" so I updated my answer.

Comment: Fixed the text, though I could have left that as an exercise for the OP ;)

Answer (score 0):

You could also use a `while` loop.

```
var START = 99;

var i = START + 1;
while(i--) {
    System.out.println(i + " bottles of beer on the wall");
    System.out.println(i + " bottles of beer");
    System.out.println("If one of those bottles should happen to fall");
    System.out.println(i + " bottles of beer on the wall");
}
```

Comment: `(i - 1)` for the last line.

Comment: @xufox: That's what `i--` was trying to accomplish inside the `while` condition. Doesn't java have those? I only know JavaScript.

Comment: `i--` is only decrementing after the last line, but the song goes like this: 99 bottles […], 99 bottles […], if one […] (actually “take one out, pass it around” or so…), _98_ bottles […]. The loop would print the last line as “99 bottles […]”, but it should be “98 bottles […]”, hence `(i - 1) + " bottles `…`"`.